# Microscopic derivation of Lindblad operators for generalized subsystem induced by observable sub-algebra (a la Zanardi)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

Consider a quantum system with two parts, the system $S$ and environment $E$, described by the tensor-product structure $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{E}$.  When the dynamics of reduced state $\rho(t) = \mathrm{Tr}_E[|\psi(t)\rangle\langle\psi(t)|]$ (with $|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt}|\psi(0)\rangle$ the evolving global state) can be approximated as Markovian, it is well known the reduced state evolves according to Lindblad master equation $$\partial_t \rho = -i[\rho,H_S]+\sum_k \left[L_k\rho L_k^\dagger + (L_k^\dagger L_k \rho + \rho L_k^\dagger L_k)/2\right]$$ for effective self-Hamiltonian $H_S$ and some set of Lindblad operators $L_k$. The Lindblad operators can be derived from the ("microscopic") Hamiltonian $H$ generating the overall dynamics under certain approximation assumptions (generally, the Born-Markov and rotating-wave/secular approximations) that guarantee the reduced dynamics of $\rho_S$ are Markovian.  This is done in, e.g., Sec. 3.3 of "Theory of Open Quantum Systems" by Petruccione & Breuer.

However, one might consider the more general notion of a subsystem induced by an arbitrary algebra of observables $\mathcal{A} = \langle \{A_i\} \rangle$ closed under multiplication and linear combinations.  This notion has been studied by many, including Zanardi [[arXiv:quant-ph/0103030](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0103030)][[arXiv:quant-ph/0308043](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308043)]. In particular, this generalized subsystem is defined by the structure theorem for matrix algebras ("Artin-Wedderburn-type structure"), leading to the decomposition
$$\mathcal{H} = \bigoplus_m \mathcal{S}_m\otimes\mathcal{E}_m$$
of the Hilbert space, which reduces to the previous special case $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{E}$ when the direct sum over $m$ is trivial.  One can then define a reduced state $$\rho_S = \bigoplus_m \rho_{S_m} = \bigoplus_m \mathrm{Tr}_{E_m}[|\psi_m\rangle\langle\psi_m|]$$ where $|\psi_m\rangle$ is obtained by projecting $|\psi\rangle$ into the subspaces labeled by $m$.  If the dynamics of $\rho_S$ are Markovian, it too will obey a Lindblad equation.

**My question**: Where can I find a careful microscopic derivation of the Lindblad operators $L_k$ and self-Hamiltonian $H_S$ from the global Hamiltonian $H$ in this more general situation?

Comment: I have been trying to find something similar today. I found this [Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2122) very useful.